# Cannot find image saved to cloud from preview

Tags: macos, icloud

I wanted to post a cropped image on FaceBook.
I scanned the image into preview (import from scanner), cropped it and when "save in the cloud" was suggested I was quite happy to save it there.

Then I clicked image in FaceBook, clicked photos, but could not find the image anywhere. No Cloud folder and not in my stream. It is only available to preview as far as I can see.

Where can I find my image back when in an upload dialog?

PS: Today I wanted to upload a few flagged images from iPhoto, but they also did not show in the "Flagged images" in the upload dialog.

Any suggestions as to how to

a) find images saved to the cloud from my iMac when uploading and
b) refresh the flagged folder in the upload dialog

System: Latest Mountain Lion and iOS6.0.1 on all other devices

Answer (score 1):

All iCloud documents get saved locally to ~/Library/Mobile Documents and preview has a folder there named com~apple~Preview with a Documents folder.

From Finder use Shift-Command-G to go to the folder

```
 ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Preview/Documents
```

You can then copy or move the file elsewhere as needed.

Comment: Great but why do they not show in the upload interface???

Comment: Good question - without poking at the system and testing some uploads it's hard to tell what or why the chain is slow to react or broken.

Comment: Maybe not consider iCloud a handy place to save to. Not as far as easy retrieval goes. Save to computer, yes. Save to Photostream, yes--tho that has to be done in iPhoto--and then it will be on any iDevices.